# QGIS 2.x - no repository and WMS access

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, repository

Suddenly in my QGIS 2.x installations the official QGIS repository is unavailable from my computer. Also I can't load any WMS (from OpenLayers plugin etc.). It worked before and I don't know what I did that causes the problem.

No difference between OSGeo4W and stand alone installations.

I deleted QGIS in the registry and reinstalled QGIS but the problem persists.
I adjusted the firewall but the problem persists.

With QGIS 1.8 on the same machine there is no problem.

From other computers in the office there is no problem connecting to the repository and getting WMS tiles with QGIS 2.x (no proxy necessary, no firewall adjustments).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the QGIS options to ensure you aren't trying to send data through a proxy.

Comment: Try to delete .qgis2 folder from User directory and to rule out a problem with the firewall try to temporarily disable them. Sometimes additional antymalware software can block WMS connections to - try to disable temporarily, if you have any.

Comment: Thanks for your hints! My proxy in QGIS is disabled. I deleted .qgis2 folder and installed QGIS via OSGeo4W again. Also I disabled the firewall. But the problem persists. Also on Ubuntu in my virtual machine I have the same problem.